# How to hide a line by default when using a checkbox in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

We can easily make an interactive graph with Bokeh where the user can toggle a line on and off but I haven’t found a way to hide the line by default (i.e before the user checks a checkbox). As an example, the code below kind of works but when the user first load the page, all the lines are on by default even know none of them are active (active=[]). The user must then select any checkbox to make them disappear and then select a given checkbox to display a given line which is clumsy. So how would one hide the lines by default before the user selects one of them?

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS

output_file("toggle_lines.html")


  ### Main plot
  plot = figure()

# Dummy data for testing
  x = list(range(90))
  y0 = [ a**1.5 for a in x]
  y1 = [ a**1.55 for a in x]
  y2 = [ a**1.60 for a in x]
  y3 = [ a**1.65 for a in x]

  l0 = plot.line(x, y0, color='red')
  l1 = plot.line(x, y1, color='red')
  l2 = plot.line(x, y2, color='red')
  l3 = plot.line(x, y3, color='red')

  checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["l0",  "l1", "l2", "l3"], active=[])
  checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(l0=l0, l1=l1, l2=l2, l3=l3, checkbox=checkbox),
                             code="""
                                  l0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
                                  l1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
                                  l2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
                                  l3.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
                                  """)
layout = row(checkbox, plot)
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `.visible = False` in the python code, for any that you want to start off invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to note that the JS code is wrong here, the correct code is

```
          l0.visible = checkbox.active.includes(0);
```

etc, etc